# Colored files in Windows terminal via Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, colors, terminal, cygwin

I have Cygwin installed on my Win7 laptop and by editing my Windows path variable I'm able to get Linux commands in my Windows command terminal. My Question is there a way to get colored file output to transfer to the Windows command line?

Through Cygwin I obviously just alias my .bashrc file, but from Googling and checking Cygwin FAQs I can't find any way to reference that file in a Windows prompt. Although 'ls --color=auto' does work, is there a way to alias this through the Windows command line in any way?

Comment: You want to use Cygwin while in a non-cygwin terminal window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Al G - Yes. I already can use commands by editing my PATH to include the Cygwin /bin directory but I was wondering if there was a way to carryover aliases. However I was able to answer my own question:

Using naitve Windows aliasing via DOSKEY I can create an alias for ls to auto color file types like this:

```
DOSKEY ls=ls --color=auto
```

Comment: To add to this, in order to make the aliases persistent across additional cmd.exe runs the only way I've found it so make a shortcut to CMD and specify in the 'target' field of the shortcut:
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K C:\path\to\aliasfile\alias.cmd

In the alias.cmd file specify:
@echo off
doskey ls=ls --color=auto
doskey anyotheraliasesyouwant

And they will be loaded at the start of the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Put the alias in the .bash_profile (create if not present), not in .bashrc.
In my case:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto -la'
```